# extraer el complemento al comparar 2 columnas en pandas y que la tercera sea ese complemento

Tags: pandas, jupyter

[image: La columna concentración es el resultado,]

La columna concentración es el resultado, el  complemento al comparar las 2 primera columnas.

Comment: Heee... y que has intentado?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461377/separar-en-pandas-la-marca-del-producto-y-la-concentraci%c3%b3n-en-columnas-diferente

Comment: En ese link esta el proceso y mi código que estaba haciendo estimado.

Comment: creo que deberías colocar todo en una sola pregunta así se entenderá mas