# Separar en Pandas la Marca del producto y la Concentración en columnas diferentes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Quiero limpiar el nombre de la marca y separar de la concentración, pero mi código no aplica para todos los casos. Aquí abajo dejé una imagen.
En la columna *concentración*, como se puede ver, se cumple para los 2 primeros casos pero para el último no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
S.str.extract('([0-9]{1,12}.[0-9]{1,12}\s?\w+.*|[0-9]{1,12}\s?\w+.*|[0-9]{1,12}.[0-9]{1,12}\s?%.*|[0-9]{1,12}\s?%.*)')
```

| MARCA GENERAL | CONCENTRACION | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PARACETAMOL forte 500MG/2ml | 500MG | 500MG |
| extradiol benzina plus 5222ui/7ml | 5222ui/7ml | 5222ui/7ml |
| DENZPIL® Ext. | Allium cepae 10 g + Heparina sódica 5000 UI + Alantoína 10mg | 10 g + Heparina sódica 5000 ui |
| MIRACRYL A | 0.05% + 0.5% | 0.05% + 0.5% |
| SUPER PLUS 1+1 | 100mg | 100mg |
| CARNITINE 1500 NATURAL LEMON (MET-RX) | 1.42ml + 0.01ml | 1.42ml + 0.01ml |
| BACTRIM FORTE | 400mg + 80mg/5 ml | 400mg + 80mg/5 ml |
| METAMIZOL SODICO | 20 mg/2.5 g/5 ml | 250mg + 15mg/5ml |
| REUMODOL FORTE | 7.6 g + 29 g | 7.6 g + 29 g |

Tengo esta marca `DENZPIL® Ext. Allium cepae 10 g +  Heparina sódica 5000 UI + Alantoína 10mg` pero no cumple mi código para esta marca: me bota como resultado `10 g + Heparina sódica 5000 ui + Alantoína 10mg` y el resultado correcto debería ser `10g + 500 ui + 10mg` (solo la concentración).

Comment: Ya lo puse como texto mi Código estimado.

Comment: Correcto, lo hago en JUPYTER NOTEBOOK

Comment: para la próxima coloca todas las etiquetas correspondientes, en un momento hago la respuesta.

Comment: Ok estimado. muchas gracias !

Comment: Tienes razón estimado, gracias!!

Comment: Esta bien estimado, quería subir el archivo CSV pero no puedo, o quizás desconozco de ello. Espero su respuesta Estimado !! y gracias por la atención.

Comment: no tengo mucho conocimiento de ello, pero puedes copiar y pegar los datos

Comment: Ya puse los datos estimado.

Comment: muy bien, muchas gracias, ahora si trabajare en la respuesta, si es posible añade mas explicación e indica el resultado deseado, pues yo lo entiendo por tu pregunta anterior, pero otras personas puede que no :).

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación estimado, ya lo puse mas explicativo.

Answer (score 0):

Bien comencemos, para hacer lo que quieres se puede hacer fácilmente con una expresión regular, como veo que lo que quieres es solo obtener los números, pues crearemos una expresión para solo obtener los números.

Simule tu *DataFrame*

```py
#importamos los modulos requeridos
import pandas as pd
import re

#creamos el DF
cols = ["MARCA GENERAL","CONCENTRACION"]
data = [["PARACETAMOL forte 500MG/2ml","500MG"],
["extradiol benzina plus 5222ui/7ml","5222ui/7ml"],
["DENZPIL® Ext. Allium cepae 10 g +  Heparina sódica 5000 UI + Alantoína 10mg","10 g + Heparina sódica"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

#creammos la expresion regular
regex = re.compile(r'\d+\w+\/\d+\w+|\d+\s{,1}\D{,1}\w+') #solo obtiene los numeros seguido de letras

#operamos en el dataFrame
df["resultado"] = df["MARCA GENERAL"].apply(lambda x: "+".join(regex.findall(x)))
```

Con `df["resultado"]` indicamos que el resultado se almacenará en una nueva columna, luego escogemos la columna `MARCA GENERAL` y utilizamos el método `apply()` para aplicarle alguna operación, en este caso indicamos que para cada valor de la fila, le aplicaremos la expresión regular `regex.findall(x)`, esto nos retornará una lista con todas las coincidencias (por eso se utilizó `findall`) y para unirlos de forma `500+2` utilizamos el método `"".join` el cual une los elementos de una lista en base al carácter que le indiquemos, en este caso `+`.
**Resultado**

|  | MARCA GENERAL | CONCENTRACION | resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PARACETAMOL forte 500MG/2ml | 500MG | 500MG/2ml |
| 1 | extradiol benzina plus 5222ui/7ml | 5222ui/7ml | 5222ui/7ml |
| 2 | DENZPIL® Ext. Allium cepae 10 g + Heparina só... | 10 g + Heparina sódica | 10 g+5000 UI+10mg |
| 3 | MIRACRYL A 0.05% + 0.5% | 0.05% + 0.5% | 0.05+0.5 |
| 4 | SUPER PLUS 1+1 100mg | 100mg | 1+1+100mg |
| 5 | CARNITINE 1500 NATURAL LEMON (MET-RX) 1.42ml +... | 1.42ml + 0.01ml | 1500 NATURAL+1.42ml+0.01ml |
| 6 | BACTRIM FORTE 400mg + 80mg/5 ml | 400mg + 80mg/5 ml | 400mg+80mg+5 ml |
| 7 | METAMIZOL SODICO 20 mg/2.5 g/5 ml | 20 mg/2.5 g/5 ml | 20 mg+2.5+5 ml |
| 8 | REUMODOL FORTE 7.6 g + 29 g | 7.6 g + 29 g | 7.6+29 g |

La expresión regular `re.compile(r'\d+\w+\/\d+\w+|\d+\s{,1}\D{,1}\w+')` indica que solo cogerá el valor si es que hay un numero seguido de una barra `/`, seguido de otro numero seguido de letras y si no coincide con este probara la segunda expresión, que es, un numero seguido de 1 o ningún espacio seguido de un carácter no alfanumérico seguido de letras, ósea que coincide con `10 g` (un numero, un espacio y letras), también con `500MG` (un numero y letras) y también con `0.05%`

Comment: El resultado que requiero es el numero y la Concentración junta. Para el primer caso como resultado preciso seria 500MG para la siguiente marca como resultado seria 5222UI/7ML  y para la ultima Marca seria 10G + 500 UI + 10MG

Comment: cambiamos la expresión regular :), ahora lo edito

Comment: @HebertLopezChavez la respuesta fue editada

Comment: El / es importante estimado ya que para medicamentos es mas minucioso.                  Estimado tendrá algún medio de contacto para poder comunicarme con usted ya que para unos casos no cumple y poder tener un mejor feedback.

Comment: @HebertLopezChavez la respuesta fue editada, se agrego una expresión regular mas

Comment: muchas gracias estimado, aunque para estas marcas no me funciona el codigo

Comment: para cuales?, podrias decirme

Comment: muchas gracias estimado, aunque para estas marcas no me funciona el codigo.                 LIQuiD L-CARNITINE 1500 NATURAL LEMON (MET-RX) 1.42ml + 0.01ml                                                                                  
MIRACRYL A 0.05% + 0.5% , Super PLUS 1+1 100mg,  INFASURF 35 mg/ml + 0,7mg/ml , BACTRIM FORTE 400mg + 80mg/5 ml
METAMIZOL SODICO 20 mg/2.5 g/5 ml ,  OXANTEL 750/750 mg/5 ml  , FORTE 7.6 g + 29 g

Comment: Siguieron que lo pongas en los datos de arriba, aquí no se visualiza muy bien

Comment: Ok estimado, ya actualice la lista. Ahí esta adicional las marcas la cual el código no funciona.

Comment: @HebertLopezChavez volví a editar la respuesta

Comment: 0.05+0.5 deberia quedar = 0.05% + 0.5%                                                                         1+1+100mg deberia quedar = 100mg                                                                            1500 NATURAL+1.42ml+0.01ml deberia quedar asi =  1.42ml+0.01ml                        20 mg+2.5+5 ml deberia quedra =  20 mg/2.5 g/5 ml                                                 7.6+29 g deberia quedar = 7.6g+29 g                                                                        Cada numero siempre va estar asociado a una concentracion no puede estar solo un numero.

Comment: el programa no es inteligente, deberás armar una expresión regular acorde a todos tus requerimientos, te mostré la lógica de como hacerlo, implementa o cambia cosas, si no entiendes la lógica estarás perdido al momento de cambiar algo

Comment: esta expresion regular es la que mejor da resultado `\d+MG|\d+ml|\d+mg|\d+ui|\d\.\d+\D+`

Comment: Esta bien, muchas gracias estimado!!!